# Finding files through Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 terminal

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10-universal

I am just beginning to work with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and c++ in general.  My professor is requiring us to run a demo he provided and recommended for Windows users use Ubuntu.

My problem is that I don't know how to access the demo folder saved on my computer using the *cd* command.

```
cd c/users
-bash: cd: /c/users: No such file or directory
```

I was told it worked just like the Command Prompt, but I'm lost at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use command `df -h`, you will see something like this

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          112G  102G  9.3G  92% /
none            112G  102G  9.3G  92% /dev
none            112G  102G  9.3G  92% /run
none            112G  102G  9.3G  92% /run/lock
none            112G  102G  9.3G  92% /run/shm
none            112G  102G  9.3G  92% /run/user
C:              112G  102G  9.3G  92% /mnt/c
D:               98G   82G   17G  84% /mnt/d
E:              136G  133G  2.9G  98% /mnt/e
```

That result means `C:` is mounted to `/mnt/c`, `D:` is mounted to `/mnt/d`, etc

So you can access `c:/users` folder by run command:

```
cd /mnt/c/users
```